# use a julia iterator as a regular vector

Tags: vector, iterator, julia

I was quite puzzled by the following,

```
sqrt(1:3) * [1 2 3]
# 3x3 Matrix, as expected
sqrt(1:3) * 1:3
# error `colon` has no method matching...
```

until I realised that 1:3 must be a different kind of beast, i.e not just a vector as I expected from Matlab. My current workaround is to use `hcat` to convert it to a vector, `sqrt(1:3) * hcat(1:3...)`, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof(1:3)` gives `UnitRange{Int64} (constructor with 1 method)`, whereas `typeof([1:3])` gives: `Array{Int64,1}`. Note that `[1:3]` is by default a column vector, so you need to transpose it: `sqrt(1:3) * [1:3].'`

Comment: thanks, I hadn't thought of using `[]` to perform the conversion. Would it be equivalent to `convert(Array,1:3).'` ?

Comment: Apparently they are not equivalent. If you put `@which` in the beginning of your line, you can see which line in base julia at abstractarray.jl is doing it, which is great by the way! For example: `@which [1,2,3]` gives: `vcat{T<:Number}(X::T<:Number...) at abstractarray.jl:518 `.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with the second version

```
sqrt(1:3) * 1:3
```

is actually operator precedence. The colon operator is very low precedence, so this translates to

```
(sqrt(1:3) * 1):3
```

which is nonsensical, hence the error

```
 ERROR: `colon` has no method matching colon(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64)`
```

Having said that, if you "fix it" with parentheses it doesn't work because the operator isn't defined. Hence you probably want `sqrt(1:3) * [1:3]'`.

Comment: indeed, it was my first idea, but I tried with parentheses and also got an error so I stopped at that point and admitted defeat